# CSS won't be loaded at iframe in Internet Explorer(IE)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iframe

ifram in Internet Explorer (Latest Version) is not able to load my css while Chrome, Safari, Firefox are having no trouble loading the css in iframe.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
                            src="/webapp/page1/card.html?customization=default"></iframe>
```

My style files are correctly connected to the iframe page using the following line:

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/webapp/load-css/BNP/default/css/default.css?loc=1" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/webapp/load-css/css/default.css?loc=4" />
```

here is a full header of html in iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" class="flexNav-no-touch">
 <head>
  <meta name="copyright" content="Atos" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="email=no" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; user-scalable=1;" /> 
  <title>Capture card details page</title> 
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/webapp/load-css/BNP/default/css/default.css?loc=1" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/webapp/load-css/css/default.css?loc=4" />
```

Comment: make sure that css links are working. You can inspect it using chrome web tools.

Comment: it is working, because I have no problems with Chrome browser by using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

And if

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]
< script src = "//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" > < /script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Css files are available in the specified directory?

Comment: yes, they are available in the specified directory.

Comment: URL to the iframe HTML page is:
http://localhost:9090/webapp/page1/card.html

and URL to CSS file is:
http://localhost:9090/webapp/load-css/BNP/default/css/default.css?loc=1

can it be the cause for that error?

Comment: <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../webapp/load-css/BNP/default/css/default.css?loc=1" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../webapp/load-css/css/default.css?loc=4" />